# Parse Movie File Name With NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

how i can parse a string of a movie file name like this:

```
Tokarev.2014.iTA.ENG.1080p.Bluray.x264-NHD.mkv
```

with `NSRegularExpression` to get the title name, the year and the quality of the movie?

For example, the result should be:

```
Name: Tokarev
Year: 2014
Quality: 1080p
```

or this:

```
300 L'alba di un impero (2014) 1080p.mkv
```

should be:

```
Movie: 300 L'alba di un impero
Year: 2014
Quality: 1080p
```

thanks!